# WELD-001303 with JSF Flows Packaged in EAR File - WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped

Tags: jsf, glassfish, wildfly, java-ee-7, glassfish-4.1

Converting a WAR file using JSF Flows into an EAR file. WAR file structure is:

```
booking/booking-flow.xml
booking/booking.xhtml
booking/confirm.xhtml
booking/print.xhtml
booking/showtimes.xhtml
WEB-INF/classes/org/javaee7/movieplex7/booking/Booking.class
WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
WEB-INF/template.xhtml
WEB-INF/web.xml
```

`faces-config.xml` is:

```xml
<faces-config version="2.2"
          xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
</faces-config>
```

`web.xml` is:

```xml
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CLIENT_WINDOW_MODE</param-name>
    <param-value>url</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

`booking-flow.xml` is:

```xml
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

<flow-definition id="booking">
    <flow-return id="goHome">
        <from-outcome>/index</from-outcome>
    </flow-return>
</flow-definition>

</faces-config>
```

JSF Flow works fine when packaged as a WAR file. But it gives the following error:

`org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped`

when this is packaged as a WAR file within an EAR file. EAR structure is:

```
booking-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
./lib
./lib/contracts-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

`booking-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war` structure is:

```
booking/booking-flow.xml
booking/booking.xhtml
booking/confirm.xhtml
booking/print.xhtml
booking/showtimes.xhtml
WEB-INF/beans.xml
WEB-INF/classes/org/javaee7/movieplex7/booking/Booking.class
WEB-INF/classes/org/javaee7/movieplex7/booking/MainPage.class
WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
WEB-INF/web.xml
```

`MainPage` class is required to retrieve the results from REST endpoint. Resource library contracts are stored in the lib directory.

Deploying the application on GlassFish 4.1.

Any idea why this works in standalone WAR file but not when packaged in EAR file?

Comment: What's in the contracts jar file?

Comment: Contracts is the JSF Resource Library Contracts and used by other WAR files for a consistent look-and-feel.

Comment: Are there any flow scoped beans in there?

Comment: Of course, the complete code base is at: https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-hol/tree/msa/solution/movieplex7-ear

Comment: ah ha.  My hunch is that the spec is being interpreted as only apply flow scope to WAR files, not libraries packaged within an ear.  Similar issues occur with all CDI scopes, since app scoped might be per war file, per app lib, or even globally depending on app server.  i hate ears :-(

Comment: Is this a known issue and filed for the spec?

Answer (score -1):

Where are you deploying? When upgrading AS7.1.1 to use JSF2.2, https://developer.jboss.org/thread/203257 was helpful.  They point out FlowScoped would not work on AS7.1.1 (and potentially other features)

Comment: JSF 2.2 is a Java EE 7 feature and so only WildFly 8.x or GlassFish would work. For now, trying on GlassFish and getting this error.